# Can a client based application be automated?

Tags: qtp

I am trying to automate an application which is client based, i.e  accessed using citrix. Tried this using QTP 9.5, 10, load runner, scapa etc. but in Vain.

Can anybody let me know -
1) Is it possible to automate citrix based application?
2) If yes then how and if no, proper justification (as we need to inform same to our customer)

Answer (score 2):

QTP supports testing applications on Citrix but it means that QTP must be installed on the Citrix machine.

Comment: Motti, i perfectly agree with you, what I am trying to know is the application is on other system (say A) and QTP on other (say B). I have QTP installed on system B in which I am accessing the application via citrix server. So it is possible to do so? Currently QTP is identifying the entire window as remote object and not individual objects of application. :(

So other than QTP, do we have any tool which will help to achieve this?

Comment: If you use the Citrix support of QTP's, you need to have QTP where the Citrix client is running. If you use a remote control to access the citrix client, you indeed can use QTP on the remote control client, but QTP will only see the remote control window, which might be just a pixel bitmap for QTP (vnc, and most others), or an RDP window (if you do an rdp connection), which kinda limits you to bitmap-based scripting.

Comment: True..!! I surfed some sites and found reference of Eggplant tool, to serve the purpose of image based automation. But I doubt this will serve my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

In Citrix automation the applications are streamed to the client computer as an image, thus you can not access to the UI tree of elements. If you can install automation tools on the Citrix machine it's perfect, if not there are also other ways to deal with image automation.

When access to the Citrix server is not possible UiPath let's you [automate Citrix](http://uipath.com/automate/citrix-automation) applications (also desktop, web, java, wpf) by using some image automation specific techniques. [Here's a full tutorial](http://pages.uipath.com/tutorials/citrix-automation-data-entry) showing different Citrix (or virtual desktops) automation techniques for

- [data entry](http://pages.uipath.com/tutorials/citrix-automation-data-entry)
- [OCR data scraping](http://pages.uipath.com/tutorials/citrix-automation-ocr-data-extraction)
- [clicking and typing relative to an image or text](http://pages.uipath.com/tutorials/citrix-automation-click-scraped-text)

It has an SDK that can be used from code. It's easier to create visual automation (workflows) directly from UiPath Studio.

[image]

Note: I work at UiPath. You should also try other visual automation tools like Automation Anywhere, WinAutomation, Jacada, use them side by side and choose the one that suits you the best.